# Custom picketlink identity store (using JOOQ)

Tags: jooq, picketlink

I want to implement authentication with Picketlink in my application, but I am not using `JPA` (instead, I'm using `JOOQ`). Is there any way to acquire user data using generated `daos`?

I couldn't find it out by reading documentation or looking at [quickstarts](https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-picketlink-quickstarts)

Thanks for help in advance